# Why aren't "I compiled X from source or installed from PPA questions" considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It seems to me that a LARGE number of not useful for most users of askubuntu questions come from this area.  Other than driver bugs, it seems to be the second most chain-gunned question that clogs up the horribly useful for new user questions.  If there's a reason, I'm completely cool with that.  It's just a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because these can probably be solved with the installation of an extra missing package or instruction. They are on topic!

They do not ask for solving issues with the source, they do not involve asking for issues with the packages.

**They are off topic if:**

- They ask to solve an issue with the package or the source it self (bug)
- They ask for features and changes on the source or package (off topic by default)

**They are on topic if:**

- They ask how to install
- They ask how to solve a fault during build
- They ask how to sort PPA dependencies and installation/removal issues

These can easy be sorted (and most cases are), we are working always on this and the flag queue shows good judgment from users flagging them.

I do not see the issue with them and **we should not be flagging all PPA or source issues as off topic!**

Comment: This is true enough.  A recent case that comes to mind is the gimp from PPA thing.  When you start saying PPA is okay, then you get in to "but I want to get this PPA without that one" questions or "why do I have broken dependency chain?" questions.  Just seems like either carte blanche acceptance or universal no is required to make it reasonable.

Comment: @aking1012 Those 2 cases seem to be on topic and answerable.